# I cant install properly Angular CLI and make it work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have run `npm install -g @angular/cli` and i tried to create a new angular project but i receive the folowing error:

```
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Chrysa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

So i tried to uninstall angular cli with `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and reinstall it with the first command but something strange happened. I notice that a new folder created on my desktop with two folders init with names npm-globalnpm and npm-globalnpm-cache. I am confused. I dont know why this happened. Is there any possibility somenthing have broken when i change something in the path of environment varibles in the past? Someone told me to change something in the path in order to solve another problem and i thing i broke something there or this is irrelevant. I dont know

Comment: Npm should not create these folders to your desktop path. You may want to completely uninstall nodejs and reinstall again. It should fix your environmental variables.

Comment: I did it and i have the same problem